# Is it possible to ignore a system check error in Django 1.7+

Tags: django, django-authentication

I'm running into the following issue:
I have an older (recently upgraded to Django 1.6) site that uses one-to-one relations for user profiles, but the FK references to certain models are pointing to auth.User. I'm building a site in 1.8 on a separate subdomain that uses the same database with the old one and uses two apps from the old one but has a custom auth model class. I know what I'm doing and want different tables for the users of both sites. But the system check for the new site fails with the fields.E301 error:

```
core.RecipientAccount.created_by: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
```

Is it possible to work around this? Or will I simply have to use 1.6 for the new site or write lots of custom migrations to refactor the old one?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution to the problem for the time being. Ultimately I'd refactor the old project to use a custom user model of it's own. But a temporary fix is using a subclass of ForeignKey to reference django.contrib.auth.User which skips the check for swapped model.

```
class ForeignKeySkipsSwappedCheck(models.ForeignKey):

    def check(self, **kwargs):
        from django.db.models.fields.related import RelatedField
        errors = super(RelatedField, self).check(**kwargs)
        errors.extend(self._check_related_name_is_valid())
        errors.extend(self._check_relation_model_exists())
        errors.extend(self._check_clashes())
        return errors
```